# How can we generate PWA with Flutter.io

Tags: flutter

I want to develop a mobile app with flutter.io.

Can I also generate PWA with the framework? similar like we can generate with ionic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Since Flutter is not html/JS/css based

But you can share code with an AngularDart app. More details [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLHln7wHgPE)

Answer (score 0):

There's currently 2 ways to have a **PWA** app on **Flutter**:

- Use [**PWA**](https://pub.dev/packages/pwa) PubDev library.
- Flutter Channel Dev **(at Feb 17, 2020 current version is 1.15.3)**

If you opt to use Channel Dev, on existence project, use the terminal to hit the command:

`flutter create .`

if we create a new project, you would have a 2 files: **`manifest.json`** and **`index.html`** inside your **web** folder.

While checking **`index.html`** you would notice the following script:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigation) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
     navigator.serviceWorker.register('/flutter_service_worker.js');
  });
}
```

This script creates the **PWA** support for you and be able to "install" the app on a device (this also includes **MacOS**)

Follow this **[GUIDE](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/migrate-to-progressive-web-apps/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)** to complete your **PWA** functionalities.